# Myhill-Nerode to prove a language is non-regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

L = {a^n b^2n c^3n | n∈N^+}
I'm trying to prove that L is a non regular language using Myhill-Nerode theorem.

Comment: Please elaborate on the issues you're having. What is your question exactly?

Comment: How do I prove that L is non regular language using nerode theorem?

Comment: You need to prove there is an infinite number of equivalence classes in the relation induced by the language. For instance, consider the strings $a^k b$, for each $k$ you get a separate equivalence class.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the basic principle: A regular language has a finite state machine. If we are given x and y, and there exists a z such that xz is in L and yz is not, or xz is not in L and yz is, then parsing x and parsing y leaves us in different states.

If we find an infinite number of pairs (x, y) such that parsing x and parsing y produces a different state, then the language is not regular.

So find these pairs. It is actually quite obvious. For example a^5 b^5 c^15 is in L but a^6 b^5 c^15 isn't, therefore...